# unexpected '}' in R Programming

Tags: r

I trying to use following piece code in R Studio and I'm expecting a result that calculates b for 1:3 times.

```
for(b in 1:3){+cat(b,"+",b,"=",b+b, "\n")+}
```

However I keep getting an error:

> Error: unexpected '}' in: "cat(b,"+",b,"=",b+b, "\n")+}"

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please remove the `+` `for(b in 1:3){cat(b,"+",b,"=",b+b, "\n")}`

Comment: Why do you have those pluses in there? Try `for(b in 1:3){cat(b,"+",b,"=",b+b, "\n")}`

Comment: I'm not familiar with R language, but are you sure that final plus sign (+), before the closing bracket (}) is not redundant?

Comment: My guess is that you copy/pasted from somebody's terminal output.  The "+" indicate that the code chunk isn't done being put input yet (so multiline code gets a "+" at the beginning of the line in the console automatically) but that "+" shouldn't be in the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It expects something to add, but there is nothing to the right hand side of `+`.